# Is it possible to populate a collection in an Azure Search index?

Tags: c#, azure, indexing, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

I've been currently working with Azure Search, and I stumbled upon a scenario where I have two tables: one describes a place, and the other has multiple photos for each place.

I wanted to use two indexers to populate the same index, where one would populate the place's details (name, coordinates, etc), while the other would get the photos, run a custom `WebApiSkill` that gets certain details from the photo, and add them to a complex collection on the index.

The issue is, I can't figure out how to populate that photo collection on the index. I have tried defining my `outputFieldMappings` as `Photos/*/Details`, or just `Photos/Details`, but I keep getting the same error:

```
Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: 'Output field mapping specifies target field 'Photos/*/PhotoURI' that doesn't exist in the index'
```

Considering this, I would like to know if it is at all possible to populate a complex collection like this in Azure Search, and if it is, how would I go about doing it?

---

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Places
(
    Id             bigint         not null  IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
    Name           nvarchar(50)   not null,
    Location       nvarchar(50)   not null
);

CREATE TABLE PlacePhotos
(
    PhotoURI  nvarchar(200)  not null  PRIMARY KEY,
    PlaceId   bigint         not null  REFERENCES Places (Id)
);
```

Classes used for creating the index:

```
public partial class Photo
{
    [IsSearchable]
    public string PhotoURI { get; set; }

    public List<Details> Details { get; set; }
}
public partial class Place
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable, IsFilterable, IsSortable, IsFacetable]
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    [IsSearchable, IsFilterable]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [IsSearchable, IsFilterable, IsSortable]
    public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

}
```

Indexer (with the `PlacePhotos` table as its data source):

```
private static void Create_PlacePhotos_Indexer(SearchServiceClient serviceClient)
{
    var indexerDef = new Indexer(
        name: placePhotosIndexer,
        dataSourceName: placePhotosDataSource,
        targetIndexName: index,
        skillsetName: skillset,
        schedule: new IndexingSchedule
        {
            Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0)
        },
        fieldMappings: new List<FieldMapping>
        {
            new FieldMapping("PlaceId", "Id"),
            new FieldMapping("PhotoURI", "PhotoURI")
        },
        outputFieldMappings: new List<FieldMapping>
        {
            new FieldMapping("/document/Id", "Id"),
            new FieldMapping("/document/PhotoURI", "Photos/*/PhotoURI"),
            new FieldMapping("/document/Details", "Photos/*/Details")
        }
    );
    serviceClient.Indexers.CreateOrUpdate(indexerDef);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Output field mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-output-field-mapping#use-outputfieldmappings) target field names must be top-level index field names, so `Photos/*/PhotoURI` is not valid and you have to target `Photos` directly.

To "shape" the `Photos` value to be mapped, you can use the [ShaperSkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-shaper#scenario-1-complex-types)

```
{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ShaperSkill",
  "context": "/document/photos/*",
  "inputs": [
    {
      "name": "PhotoURI",
      "source": "/document/photos/*/PhotoURI"
    },
    {
      "name": "Details",
      "source": "/document/photos/*/Details"
    }
  ],
  "outputs": [
    {
      "name": "output",
      "targetName": "shapedValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

and output field mapping

```
new FieldMapping("/document/photos/*/shapedValue", "Photos")
```

**NOTE** - you might have to rearrange your skills that output URI and details, so they share a common `context`. From your snippet above it looks like each `document` has only 1 photo, which is different from your index definition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There's just one detail I'm not understanding: would a mapping like this effectively populate a complex field? If I generated multiple values from multiple photos into a ``photos`` field, they would still overwrite the field with each rewrite, no?

Comment: The `Place` class defines `public List<Photo> Photos` so `Photos` is a Collection of Complex types and will expect an array of `Photo`s.

Comment: Would that mean that multiple ``Photos`` could be mapped to the collection without overwriting eachother?

Comment: The top-level `Photos` defined in `class Place` must be unique (1 per document), but each `Photos` value can contain zero or more values of `class Photo` (and each `Photo` will be stored without overwriting).
Since `Photos` is defined as `List<Photo> Photos`, it corresponds to index field type Collection(Edm.ComplexType) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types#edm-data-types-used-in-azure-search-indexes-and-documents.

Comment: So they don't overwrite eachother.. that was my fear. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: @hougumnaah did you ever manage to group the photos in the place documents using indexers?